# Photologue UnsupportedOperation('fileno',)

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have used Photologue on many projects on different servers and never had this problem before.

When Photologue calls this function
`self.create_size(photosize)`

I receive this error

```
UnsupportedOperation('fileno',)
```

I have googled for answers and found out that it may be caused by PIL and Pillow being both installed on the server.

I am using virtualenv on my sever with no-site-packages option but it seems that under mod_wsgi it still reads the system packages. I can smoothly install and uninstall PIL under my virtualenv but on the system when I uninstall PIL and the run pip freeze I still see this.

```
pip freeze
....
PIL==1.1.7
...
```

Even if I uninstall Pillow in virtuallenv and on my system I still receive the same error which makes me think that Photologue uses PIL and not Pillow. Is there a way to uninstall PIL from the system or to force Photologue to use Pillow instead of PIL?

My system:
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Python 2.7.3
Apache mod_wsgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by hard deleting the PIL lib from my system packages as even if I run my project in virtualenv it was still picking up PIL installed in the system packages. You should cautious when doing this as some other programs or project on your system can depend on it.